# React Yarn Build inside docker takes 5+ minutes

Tags: reactjs, docker, yarnpkg

It takes 5+ minutes to perform a yarn build for my codebase which is small.

Here is my dockerfile (note: I am omitting yarn install with node-modules)

```
### STAGE 1: Build
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

### STAGE 2: Run
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

I am attaching my build time reports below:

1. With node-modules package

[image]

2. Without node-modules package, ignored it in .dockerfile

[image]

Point to note: The step - optimising a production build takes the maximum time.

> [image]

The codebase is indeed small and it hardly takes ~20secs to run yarn build locally. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know your evnironment, but this had happened to me: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/10247

Comment: Running on mac M1 chip. Forgot to mention that I am building the docker image for amd64. Sharing the build cmd 

docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64 --tag asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/<..> .

Comment: any updates on that? I currently face the same issue where builds take forever ..

Answer (score -1):

Do first check Code complexity maybe because of that react take too much time for the build process or Allocate more resources to your Docker Container.
To allocate resources to your Docker container, you can use the docker run command with the -c and -m options.

For example, to allocate 2 CPU shares and 2GB of memory to a Docker container, you can use the following command:

```
docker run -c 2 -m 2g <image-name>
```

Comment: I've already allocated 5gigs of CPU and 5gigs of RAM to the entire docker engine which is required during build.